# Arch Linux in virutalbox: kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub, fstab, kernel-panic

I installed Arch Linux from arch linux evolution-image to a virtual device.
I tested the installation with GRUB MBR and GRUB efi.

Inside virtualbox, I can see the grub menu, but when I select Arch Linux it gives me a

> Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a wrong `fstab` generated by `genfstab` (as pointed out [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=196083)). So the kernel (please correct me, if this is wrong) didn't find my root-partition.

I generated `fstab` with labels and had a partition with a space in it. In fstab this must be written with `\040`. `genfstab` wrote garbage for the space.

[Other answeres](https://askubuntu.com/a/41939/358665) suggest to run `update-initramfs -u -k version`, however this command is replaced by `mkinitcpio`.

To get the system running I did this:

- I ran `grub-mkcofnig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` (probably not important in this case)
- after that I booted into grub-menu and pressed **c** for the grub-shell
  I started Arch Linux manually by entering the following commands:

  `insmod linux
  insmod ext2 (this works for ext3 and ext4, too or enter your filesystem-driver)
  set root=(hd0, 2) (enter your partiton-number starting from 1)
  linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda2 (again select your partition)
  initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img
  boot`
- correct `/etc/fstab` (make sure spaces are expressed as `\040`)

Finished!

Comment: Since you asked :). When you use an initrd, the kernel isn't what finds the root device. "unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)" tends to mean an initrd wasn't (successfully) loaded when it needed to be. I wonder if you were missing an initrd at that point. If the _initrd_ fails to find the root filesystem then it is different; the initrd tends to provide a nice little shell prompt, to see if you can do any better finding for it :). I researched this in the last section of my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453272/kernel-panic-while-installing-fedora-28/453307

Comment: @sourcejedi ...and the `initrd` is found by `grub` (or any other bootloader), so the `fstab` is not read at this point. I can’t tell with this much time in between anymore. But I understand, that you say, that the error message doesn’t match with what I‘ve diagnosed.

Comment: Or just check that you wrote `initrd` correctly in your config file. (Yeah, this is a note for my future-self)

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell which CPU you are using.

In Arch OS, intel-cpu.img is required for Intell CPU whereas for AMD CPU  initramfs-linux.img.

So if you are using Intell CPU, you should install intell-cpu along with linux image.

```
sduo pacman -S intell-cpu
```

For other AMD CPU, sometime Grub keep intell-cpu as microcode which also result in same situation, hence you have to update grub.cfg file manually.
Open Grub file `gksu gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and then edit the arch menuentry.

```
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg
...
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk'
initrd  /intel-ucode.img /initramfs-linux.img
...
```

Repeat it for each menu entry.