# Installation of Ubuntu 18.04 from my USB fails with error code 23

Tags: ubuntu, usb, system-installation, ssd

I am installing ubuntu on a brand new motherboard (onto m.2 ssd) using an usb

when I got to the part of extracting image from cp:///media/systemfile, it gets error. error code 23 with message:

```
file "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/curtin/utils.py, line131, in _subp cmd=args)
...tin.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
command: ['sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p "$2" && cd "$2" && rsync -aXHAS --one-file-sstem "$1/" .', '--',
...t code :23
reason : -
stdout: ''
stderror: ''
```

Can someone explain what is the cp: protocol? what is it trying to do?

and what would be error code 23 in this case?

Comment: `cp:///media/filesystem` or `cp:///media/systemfile`. Edit taken from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2401744&p=13802746#post13802746).

Comment: OS error code  23:  Too many open files in system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"23 Partial transfer due to error".  See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/rsync.1.html#exit%20values

Normally an `rsync` command would print an error message.  But curtin is being horribly unhelpful here.  It doesn't pass `capture` to `_subp()`, and as a result it sets `stderr` to `None`.  Any error messages from `rsync` are simply discarded.

- https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/curtin/blob/5f0082d/curtin/commands/extract.py#L88
- https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/curtin/blob/5f0082d/curtin/util.py#L87

While looking up curtin, I found its definition of `cp:///`.

https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/config.html#sources

> Specify the root image to install on to the target system. The URI also configures the method used to copy the image to the target system.
>
> sources:
>
> source URI may be one of:
>
> - dd-: [sic] Use dd command to write image to target.
> - cp://: Use **rsync** command to copy source directory to target.
> - file://: Use tar command to extract source to target.
> - http[s]://: Use wget | tar commands to extract source to target.
> - fsimage://: mount filesystem image and copy contents to target. Local file or url are supported. Filesystem can be any filesystem type mountable by the running kernel.

Comment: thanks, that's really deep. It was indeed due to bad image on the usb.

Comment: @bhomass thanks for the followup! I think this answers the question as written, would you like to mark it as accepted? (click on the grey tick at the right hand side).  (I thought it might be something like this :) after having troubleshooted a Fedora install failure due to a bad install image / bad usb. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453307/29483 .  As I wrote, the Fedora USB writer is great as it verifies the written image, but it's only shipped for Windows and Fedora, on generic Linux you kind of have to resort to `cmp` on the command line).